# Where can I find or what API can i use to find the lang/long of a certain place?

Tags: iphone

I am making an app which you open it up and it will use your lang/long point to find the nearest ( for example: shop ) what api, or what would i need to do this?

/* this app is for the iPhone *\

Comment: There are two questions here; one is about finding the location of the user's iPhone. The other is about finding the location of nearby shops &c. CoreLocation is the library that answers the first. The answer to the second is more complicated (there are many libraries that do that sort of thing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the [CoreLocation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=CoreLocation)

Comment: Cheers for you help much appreciated.

Comment: @Alex Be sure to look at the last couple of answers about Yahoo PlaceFinder and Google Local Search for the answer to the second half of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Read the [CLLocation docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) and [Core Location Data Types](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in API to find the nearest shop/restaurant/whatever, but you can make requests to the **[Google Local Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/index.html)** to find them.

Note that this API is deprecated and will be phased out over the next 3 years, but I'm sure something will replace it.

Comment: A comment as to why you downvoted my answer would be greatly appreciated. There are tons of apps in the store using Google Local Search, apps that can be updated when Google's replacement for it is announced. What don't you like about this answer?

Comment: i agree.. there is a proper and valid point and it got down voted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Yahoo's placefinder api:
http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/